# Como colocar pontuação em uma sql row

Tags: c, c++

Bem eu estou procurando uma forma para colocar pontuação em uma contagem de rows que é feita do meu mysql.

Se o valor retornado for acima de 1000 ele inserir pontuações, por exemplo:

- 1000 = 1.000
- 1000000 = 1.000.000

O codigo é o seguinte:

```
void sql_rows(MYSQL_ROW sql) {
   printf("a quantidade de rows é '%s'\n", sql->row[0]);
}
```

Eu sempre recebo os valores mais sem pontuação é possível adicionar uma pontuação no valor retornado de rows ?

Comment: Precisa dar mais contexto ao que está fazendo, fornecer mais código.

Comment: mais o resto do código é inútil, por que tem nada que possa ajudar referente a isso, e esse MYSQL_ROW é da API do mysql. a questão mesmo é que a rows retorna como uma string, se fosse inteiro seria mais facil.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma função que escreva o número aos pedaços, e insira os pontos entre eles:

```
void
escrever_numero(unsigned int n, FILE * stream) {
    char buf[10];
    char * ptr = buf;
    size_t nchar, i, j;

    // escreve número no buffer
    nchar = sprintf(buf, "%d", n);
    // Quantos dígitos preciso escrever para a primeira classe?
    i = nchar % 3; if (!i) i = 3;
    // escrever a primeira classe
    fprintf(stream, "%.*s", i, ptr);
    // avançar
    ptr += i;
    // enquanto ainda houver classes para escrever,
    // escreva um ponto e depois a classe
    while (*ptr) {
        fputc('.', stream);
        fprintf(stream, "%.3s", ptr);
        // não esqueça de avançar o ponteiro
        ptr += 3;
    }
}
```

Aí é só pôr no lugar do `printf()` a chamada a esta função:

```
void sql_rows(MYSQL_ROW sql) {
    puts("a quantidade de rows é ");
    escrever_numero(sql->row[0], stdout);
    puts("\n");
}
```

Note que a função que escrevi só trabalha com inteiros não-negativos, mas isso serve para o caso específico de contagem de linhas (ou de qualquer outra coisa). Se precisar de uma função que trate números negativos, basta tratar a possibilidade de existência de um sinal de menos antes da primeira classe.

Finalmente, também é possível você substituir esse parâmetro `FILE *` por um `char *` e trocar as chamadas a `fprintf()` por `sprintf()`, se quiser, mas tome cuidado para dimensionar os seus *arrays* corretamente e também terminar a *string* com um `\0`, que não precisa fazer com o `FILE *`.